# Wiener's construction of the Wiener Measure

Tags: math-history, brownian-motion, wiener-measure

I am writing an essay about Norbert Wiener and I already have sufficient info about him in general and his history, but now I would like to know how he constructed the Wiener measure. I found some constructions of the Wiener process and the Wiener measure, but I cannot establish which one was his original idea. Does anyone know any source where I can find that construction?

Comment: the Wiener process is nothing more than a gaussian i.i.d. process filtered and with the discretization step $\to 0$

Comment: *Brownian motion - An Introduction to Stochastic processes* by René Schilling & Lothar Partzsch; Section 3.3

Comment: @saz Thanks! I already found that book. I have some doubts though. It doesn't mention the Wiener measure, only the process. Is the Wiener measure defined as $\mu(A)=\mathbb{P}(W \in A)$, where $W$ is the Wiener process? Also, he proposed this construction in 1923-1924, but the formal definition of a propability space wasn't introduced until 1933.

Comment: @rafalpw The Wiener measure is mentioned in Chapter 4 (and, yes, it's defined this way). I thought you are looking for a "modern" proof using Wiener's idea.